# Steam downloading large files whilst I'm on mobile broadband

Tags: steam, napoleon-total-war

I have a CD copy of Napoleon: Total War, and installed it from disc. Now when I try to play, Steam starts trying to download files for it, 5 GB's worth. I'm on mobile broadband so I can't afford this. I have uninstalled Steam / Total War and then tried re-installing both, but still the same problem occurs. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You could tell Steam to not update games automatically, by right clicking on the game in your library and then clicking on `Properties > Updates` and choosing `Do not automatically update this game`

If for some reason, Steam still believes it needs to download *something*, you will possibly need to find a wireless or wired network other than the mobile one to download the remaining game data.

Comment: From my experience the problem is that once Steam starts updating, you cannot tell it to "stick with what you already got" later on. But maybe they improved on that meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be asking a friend who has it also installed for the file `appmanifest_34030.acf` (in Steam's subfolder steamapps, at least if 34030 is the correct ID of the game) and hope this is enough to make Steam believe it already has the game data. You may however still end up downloading *some* updates, whether you like it or not. Or your friend uses Steam's backup function and sends you two DVDs...